# Unity musical instrument in VR for MIDI output

Tags: unity-game-engine, midi, virtual-reality, htc-vive

I want to create a xylophone in VR to create MIDI output. The MIDI output is needed so my team can use it later. If I understand correctly, MIDI contains information about the instrument in the channel and several other things like the note, pitch, velocity, etc. I don't quite get how would I create a valid MIDI output in Unity from a person playing a xylophone with Vive controllers in VR. I can track the note, timing, velocity, but what parameters do I really need to create a valid MIDI output, or is it even possible in such a scenario?

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful to reiterate your question to better clarify it so that knowledgeable individuals can answer your question with relevance.

Its indefinably possible: 
https://www.twitch.tv/videos/177585172

Comment: Thanks for response. The example in the video is nice, but as fas as I know I cannot apply this directly to a virtual instrument. The goal is to have a very simple interface for the user, so he should just play the instrument without pressing any additional buttons and the midi output should be created just by that.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it's not too late for a response! (I'm aware it's been a year)
I'm developing a vr toy that does just that, sending MIDI signals when I hit, twist or interact with gameobjects, out to VCV Rack (or just any synth/DAW, since its MIDI <3)

I achieved this through midi-dot-net to turn collision events into MIDI:
https://code.google.com/archive/p/midi-dot-net/
(cool logo btw)

and then loopMIDI to open a virtual port on Windows to connect Unity to VCV.
https://www.tobias-erichsen.de/software/loopmidi.html

both are free and cake to use.
Hope this is helpful!